# Reciprocal Equation Substitution: $x^n$ + $\frac{1}{x^n}$ and Tchebychev Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

I am studying E.J Barbeau Polynomials and I'm stuck at understanding a particular problem on reciprocal equations. Let $t$ = $x$ + $\frac{1}{x}$. Defining $p_n(t)$ = $x^n$ + $\frac{1}{x^n}$, the book brings to notice the recurrence relation that $p$ satisfies. $$p_{n+1}(t) = tp_n(t)-p_{n-1}(t)$$ for $n\ge1$, with the initial conditions $p_0(t)=2$ and $p_1(t) = t$. The problem is: **test the conjecture that all coefficients of $p_n(t)$ except the leading coefficient are divisible by n when n is prime. Is this true?**
I do not know where to start with this problem. The next statement says: **Is there any connection between $p_n(t)$
 and Tchebychev polynomials of the first kind?**
Where Tchebychev Polynomial is defined as $T_n(x)$ = $cos\bigl(n*arccos(x)\bigr)$.
It is also recursively defined as $$T_{n+1}(x) = 2xT_n(x) - T_{n-1}(x)$$ for $n\ge1$, with initial conditions $T_0(x) = 1$ and $T_1(x) = x$.
Since they are so closely related in their recursive relations, I am forced to believe that they have some "*connection*" as the book states but I do not know how to proceed in this either.
I know how to solve linear homogeneous recurrences which I suspect is not enough knowledge to solve this recurrence. The explicit expression for $T_n(x)$ could be derived easily using trigonometry but I am not able to relate the problem with trigonometry either.

Comment: You give a recurrence relation where the LHS contains p,n, and t, and the RHS contains x.  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: When it suggests you *test* the conjecture, it means that you should **test** it: try various values of $n$ and see whether the results concur with it.

Comment: @Acccumulation The OP should have stated that $t=x+1/x$.

Comment: Yes sorry I shall edit it right away

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown We also need to tell if the conjecture is true or not.

Comment: "Please consider explaining without the use of calculus"?! If you want professional results, use professional tools, please.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Any solution would help a lot, with or without calculus.